# How to pass current context to an object c#

Tags: c#, authorization, credentials

I am creating an application where I first login with my user account. This user account could be windows or self managed account in my own application database.

Now I want to authorize the logged in user before accessing any business objects of my application. Objects are mapped with database tables so eventually I want to authorize user first, whether to give data back to user or not.

After logging in I store user credentials globally as an object of `UserCredential` class. But I don't want to pass this credentials to each object when I am creating it.

Is there any way to check/reach the application context (including `UserCredential` object I stored globally) for each business objects automatically which I am creating further?

I want to achieve this in C#. Code example is much appreciated.

Comment: [I suggest] Dependency Injection.

Comment: Also, don't pass around the "credentials", just the user/authorization information, which might be previously established from the credentials. In a web-service this might be established at the start of a request.

Comment: Would you please provide a sample c# code; very quick one if possible? I understood by passing authorization information. But the sample code for using Dependency injection will be much appreciated...!! - Thanks

Comment: @user2246674 - he's telling the poster of the question to post code , not you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the PrincipalPermissionAttribute class, here is the MSDN documentation:

[PrincipalPermissionAttribute class MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute.aspx)

The PrincipalPermissionAttribute throws a SecurityException when the Thread.CurrentPrincipal does not match the security assertion.

Examples:

User's name is GDroid:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "GDroid")]
public void YourBusinessMethod()
{
    // Do something
}
```

User belongs to Admin role:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Admin")]
public void YourBusinessMethod()
{
    // Do something
}
```

User is authenticated:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated = true)]
public void YourBusinessMethod()
{
    // Do something
}
```